# SSHFS over multiple connections through a gateway

Tags: ssh, mount, gateway, sshfs

I have to mount a directory from a machine which can only be accessed through an SSH connection within another SSH gateway that I have to connect first. I want to use SSHFS for mounting, is it possible to mount through the gateway (by making a connection within a connection)?

Comment: This sounds like a job for the [`ProxyJump` option](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts#Passing_Through_One_or_More_Gateways_Using_ProxyJump).

Comment: @GordonDavisson Thank you, I've managed it. I'll add an answer

Answer (score 0):

I've used `ProxyJump` as discussed in [this ServerFault question](https://serverfault.com/questions/941934/sshfs-over-a-jumphost):

```
sshfs -o ProxyJump=user@gateway_address user@workstation_address:/dir/to/be/mounted/ local_mount_dir/
```